# Data truncating after 255 characters when inserting into dataset from Excel but no issue when populating DataTable

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to insert the data from Excel file to dataset using ADO.NET. Below is the procedure adopted

1. First all excel data are loaded into dataset using

> connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=mydb.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";

1. when populating dataset it inserts only 255 characters. (I couldn't find where it is truncating). In our source code there is no code for truncating. But when same connection is used to fill a datatable no such problem occurs.

Please help me to over come this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the ACE driver is inferring a TEXT data type for the column when you're populating the data set.  Text columns are limited to 255 characters.  You need to force it to use the MEMO data type.  When you're filling the database, presumably, the database column is of a type that supports more than 255 characters, and the driver picks that up.

In addition to the methods discussed in [this thread on the problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/6dba5b86-1ad6-46c5-8428-556753b32ce4), you can force it to use the memo data type by inserting a dummy row of data and inserting 256 or more characters in the cell for that column.  (That thread concerns Jet but should also be applicable to ACE.)

Your best alternative, perhaps, is to use some other library to read the file and populate the DataSet without Jet/ACE.

Comment: Try selecting from a named range instead.

Comment: Great suggestion. I had column headings in the spreadsheet so i change the heading of problem column from My_Column_Heading in the related field to My_Column_Heading<------Including this to pad out the column width to 256-------> and ensure there were enough dashes to reach 256 characters.

Answer (score 1):

This is the cause of the issue - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/189897

It can be fixed by inserting a dummy row at the top (perhaps a header row - I have not tried this myself) with 255+ characters or more.

This seems to be a promising solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit vague about the way it gets truncated, but from the below there are a couple of possibles:-

- Worksheet size 65,536 rows by **256 columns**
- **Column width 255 characters**

From here:-

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx

> Worksheet and workbook specifications
>
> FEATURE   MAXIMUM LIMIT
>   Open workbooks    Limited by available memory and system resources
>   Worksheet size    65,536 rows by **256 columns**
>   **Column width    255 characters**
>   Row height    409 points
>   Page breaks   1000 horizontal and vertical
>   Length of cell contents (text)    32,767 characters. Only 1,024 display in a cell; all 32,767 display in the formula bar.
>   Sheets in a workbook  Limited by available memory (default is 3 sheets)
>   Colors in a workbook  56
>   Cell styles in a workbook 4,000
>   Named views in a workbook Limited by available memory
>   Custom number formats Between 200 and 250, depending on the language version of Excel you have installed.
>   Names in a workbook   Limited by available memory
>   Windows in a workbook Limited by system resources
>   Panes in a window 4
>   Linked sheets Limited by available memory
>   Scenarios Limited by available memory; a summary report shows only the first 251 scenarios
>   Changing cells in a scenario  32
>   Adjustable cells in Solver    200
>   Custom functions  Limited by available memory
>   Zoom range    10 percent to 400 percent
>   Reports   Limited by available memory
>   Sort references   3 in a single sort; unlimited when using sequential sorts
>   Undo levels   16
>   Fields in a data form 32
>   Custom toolbars in a workbook Limited by available memory
>   Custom toolbar buttons    Limited by available memory