# Import from Excel in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, import

I use following code to save data from excel file into table

```
private void RetrieveAndStoreExcelData(String filePath)
{
    String excelConnectionStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source='" + filePath + "'; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;'";
    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionStr);
    excelConnection.Open();

    try
    {
        //Get the name of the first worksheet
        DataTable schema = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        if (schema == null || schema.Rows.Count < 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: Could not determine the name of the first worksheet.");
        }
        string firstSheetName = schema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

        //Retrieve data from worksheet into reader
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [" + firstSheetName + "]";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, excelConnection);
        OleDbDataReader dbReader = command.ExecuteReader();  //IEnumerable

        //populate IEnumerable
        if (dbReader.HasRows)
        {
            populateRecords(dbReader);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        excelConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

This works fine. But if one of the fields length is greater than 255 characters then it truncates the string to 255 and that is also when that row appears after 10th row in excel sheet.

So, if first 10 rows is having length less than 255, it assumes that all rows will have length less than 255 characters.

So is there any way to solve this?

Comment: What version of Excel? Is it saved in 8.0 format?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889998/data-truncating-after-255-characters-when-inserting-into-dataset-from-excel-but

Comment: excel 2003.. also I tried in excel 2007.. but same issue

Comment: anyone there... to help out... as told by KMC I tried but it is not solved by that solution